# Nginx, static files for regex location

Tags: regex, static-files

I'm trying to configure following rule:
when an user comes to `admin.mysite.com/username` he is should get static files. I decided to use regex in location and get something like this:

```
location ~ ^\/\w+$ {
    alias $site_root/html
}
```

But it is was very surprising for me that nginx does not allow to use alias in regex location without capture group and using this group:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

> If alias is used inside a location defined with a regular expression then such regular expression should contain captures and alias should refer to these captures.

So, i want to find an workarounk, some technique that can provide necessary behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rewrite for that instead like:

```
server {
  root /some_root;
  rewrite ^/\w+$ html last;

  location /html {
    ...
  }
}
```